# What is wrong with my @Path annotation for sending multiple parameters in HTTP Requests to NetBeans?

Tags: java, android, http, netbeans, postman

What is wrong with my @Path annotation for sending multiple parameters in NetBeans? I am trying to send parameters from my Android Client to my Server but my App is crashing. I am now trying to do the same with postman but it says that the request is not found, the response is 500
I am new to this but I can not find an answer online

This is my Java code (Path parameters are not from the database, they are just regular variables that I am going to compare DB column values with)

```
 @GET
               @Path("/getFilteredRealEstateList/{min_p}/{max_p}/{min_m}/{max_m}/{number_of_rooms}/{type}/{location}") 
 @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
        
    public ArrayList<RealEstate> getFilteredRealEstates(@PathParam("min_p") int minP, @PathParam("max_p") int maxP, @PathParam("min_m") int minM,@PathParam("max_m") int maxM,@PathParam("number_of_rooms") double numberOfRooms,@PathParam("type") String type,@PathParam("location") String location) throws RealEstateException {
                   return realEstateService.findAllFilteredRealEstates(minP, maxP, minM, maxM, numberOfRooms, type, location);
```

and this is a postman request

```
http://localhost:8080/RealEstate/rest/real_estate/getFilteredRealEstateList/0/500/0/80/2/Flat/Rakovica
```

and this is SQL Query:

```
 public ArrayList<RealEstate> findFilteredAll(int minP, int maxP, int minM, int maxM, double numOfRooms, String type, String loc, Connection con) throws SQLException {
        PreparedStatement ps = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;
         ArrayList<RealEstate> realEstateList = new ArrayList<> ();
        try {
            String minPrice = (minP == 0 ? "0" : Integer.toString(minP) );
            String maxPrice = (maxP == 0 ? "100000" : Integer.toString(maxP) );
            String minM2 = (minM == 0 ? "0" : Integer.toString(minM) );
            String maxM2 = (maxM == 0 ? "10000": Integer.toString(maxM));
            
              
            ps = con.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM real_estate r JOIN location l ON r.location_id = l.location_id" +
            " WHERE (price BETWEEN ? AND ? " +
            "AND m2 BETWEEN ? AND ? " +
            "AND type LIKE '?' AND  l.locationname LIKE '?'" );
            ps.setString(1,minPrice);
            ps.setString(2, maxPrice);
            ps.setString(3, minM2);
            ps.setString(4,maxM2);
            ps.setString(5,type);
            ps.setString(6,loc);
            rs = ps.executeQuery();
            while (rs.next()) {
            Location location = LocationDao.getInstance().find(rs.getInt("location_id"), con);
            RealEstate realEstate = new RealEstate(rs.getString("image"), rs.getString("type"), rs.getString("description"),rs.getString("number"),
                           rs.getString("email"),rs.getInt("price"),rs.getInt("m2"),rs.getDouble("number_of_rooms"),location);
                realEstateList.add(realEstate);
            }
        } finally {
            ResourceManager.closeResources(rs, ps);
        }
        return realEstateList;
    }
```

Comment: Please post the StackTrace when the 500 error occurs.

Answer (score 0):

you have set first section of your URL?

```
http://localhost:8080/RealEstate/rest/real_estate/
```

and use the your system ip address instead of "localhost"

Comment: Oh, but my other requests work normally with localhost. I tried system IP address it doesn't work so i would say there is some syntax problems that i don't see . This is the only function that doesn't work, whole list without parameters is returning normally